# missing 1 required positional argument - Caesar Cipher

Tags: python, encryption

So I am creating a piece of code that converts a word into a new word (like the Caesar Cipher) but with this program the user inputs a keyword to change the message by using the ASCII values of the words to change them into a new word.

```
 exitReq = False
    while not exitReq: 
print ('-' * 45)
print('The Caesar Cipher')
time.sleep(1)
print('Tom Payne 2015')
time.sleep(1)
phrase = input('Please enter the message you want to encrypt: ').lower()
encryption = input("Do you want to [E]ncrypt or [D]ecrypt?: ").upper()
shift_key = input('Please enter the keyword/phrase you would like to be your shift key: ').lower()

def keyword_cipher(key,newletter,phrase):

    if len(phrase) > len(key):
        while len(phrase) > len(key):
            length_to_add = len(phrase) - len(key)
            key = key + key[0:length_to_add]

    elif len(phrase) < len(key):
        while len(phrase) < len(key):
            length_to_sub = len(key) - (len(key) - len(phrase))
            key = key[0:length_to_sub]

    else:
        pass

    #shift the characters
    shifted_phrase = ''
    if Encryption == ("D"):
        for i in range(len(phrase)):
            newletter == (ord(key[i]) - 96) - (ord(phrase[i]) - 90) + 96

    if Encryption == ("E"):
        for i in range(len(phrase)):
            newletter == (ord(key[i]) - 96) + (ord(phrase[i]) - 96) + 96

    if newletter > 122:
        newletter = chr(newletter - 26)
    else:
        newletter = chr(newletter)

        shifted_phrase = shifted_phrase + new_letter
    return shifted_phrase

#call it all to action
result = keyword_cipher(shift_key,phrase);

print ('Encrypted message:')
print (result)

print ('=' * 45)
time.sleep(1)
exit = input('Would you like to exit: ')
if (exit) == 'yes':
        exitReq = True
        print('Thank You. Goodbye')
        print ('-' * 45)
```

The error that occurs when I run the module is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "S:\Downloads\t2p.py", line 52, in <module>

    result = keyword_cipher(shift_key,phrase);
TypeError: keyword_cipher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'phrase'
```

Comment: Because you defined it with `def keyword_cipher(key,newletter,phrase):` you are missing the newletter?

Comment: Reading and understanding error messages is a big part of programming. I suggest, you take a little time to read that error message again (it's pretty clear), think about your code and try to fix it yourself. Your future self will thank you if you build the skills to fix those problems yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
def keyword_cipher(key, newletter, phrase):
```

by:

```
def keyword_cipher(key,phrase):
```

I guess you first write a function to encrypt a single letter then you change it to encrypt a string and forget to remove the letter argument.